# Help identify this game with four divided concentric circles

Tags: identify-this-game

I inherited the a wooden game from my parents. Probably date from 1960-1975. No box, no instruction. Can you help me identify it and locate rules for it?

It's a 9.5" square with 4 indented concentric circles. The outer ring is divided into 12 sections, the next into 8 sections, the 3rd into 4 and the center - approx 1" diam. is not divided.White and black dots are in seemingly random sections. Inside the black leather pouch are 6 brown wooden marbles and two chrome cylinders. One cylinder has 3 raised concentric circles on one end, the other has 2 concentric circles, the innermost indented. "Skjode Skjern Danmark" is etched on the bottom.

[image: Picture of the board]

Comment: Could you post images of both the games, as separate questions?

Comment: Removed one of the two games. Please post it as a separate question (with a picture). Your description can be found [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/revisions/48166/1).

Comment: The first game has been identified as "Patience" a form of Solitaire. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 11):

It is a Morra board game.
You will find details here on Board Game Geek :
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41679/morra-board

Here is their explanation of it:

> From the instructions: Morra-board builds on an ancient game - renewing and varying it by linking it to a board.
>   The old game on which Morra-board is based is in Danish called 'Klunse', in English 'Odds and Evens'. Each of the two players presents a clenched fist containing a few small stones, coins or matches - both players taking turns at guessing if the sum of the objects in the two hands is even or uneven.
>
> Players pieces move around the track based on how many total marbles the two players reveal. If the inner track has a marking on it, the piece advances. The goal is to be the first to advance all the way to the center.

Answer (score -2):

it could be Byzantine Chess , search using the pinterest search by image. you may want to include other pieces included with that board

Comment: There does not appear to be nearly enough spaces on the board for that